# Missing Detect Features properties in Blender 2.8x?

Tags: tracking, marker

According to Blender Manual (2.8)
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/movie_clip/tracking/clip/editing/track.html,
Detect Features should have properties like Placement, Margin, etc... which I can not find.

Am I missing something or this is expected behaviour in 2.8x?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found it!

Once clicked on Detect Features they appear as shown on image below (red circle).

[image]